# MySQL - Consulta em tabelas relacionadas

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

O cenário é simples, o SQL exibe todos os resultados do critério e existe um filtro para selecionar multi valores que serão passados ao SQL, que deverão consultar a `tbl2` no campo `tbl2_criterio`, e assim exibir somente os registros que contém os valores iguais aos valores do filtro.

Tentei realizar no `$where_filtro` o uso de `"AND tbl2_criterio = '" . $var_filtro[0] . "'` e os demais, mas não deu certo.

Como verificar os registros na `tbl2` no campo `tbl2_criterio` e adequar ao SQL?

Segue abaixo o que tentei até agora:

```
<?php
$where_filtro = ""; // Vazio na QUERY se $_GET['var_filtro'] não foi definido.

if( isset( $_GET['var_filtro'] ) {

    $var_filtro = $_GET['var_filtro'];
    $var_filtro = explode(",",$var_filtro);
    // Imprime: 
    // $var_filtro[0] = "valor1";
    // $var_filtro[1] = "valor2";
    // $var_filtro[2] = "valor2";

    for($i=0;$i<=count($_GET['var_filtro']);$i++) {
        $where_filtro .= " AND `tbl2_criterio` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$var_filtro[$i]) . "' ";
    }

} 

$sql = "SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            `tbl1` 
        INNER JOIN 
            `tbl2` 
        ON 
            `tbl2_id_pai` = `tbl1_id` 
        WHERE 
            `tbl1_status` = 'A' 
        " . $where_filtro . "
        ;";

$query = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) {
    echo $row['tbl1_row1']."<br>\n";
}
?>
```

O SQL fica assim depois de executado quando dou echo em $sql.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `tbl1` 
INNER JOIN 
    `tbl2` 
ON 
    `tbl2_id_pai` = `tbl1_id` 
WHERE 
    `tbl1_status` = 'A' 
AND 
    `tbl2_criterio` = 'valor1' 
AND 
    `tbl2_criterio` = 'valor2' 
AND 
    `tbl2_criterio` = 'valor3';
```

> A consulta retorna: MySQL não retornou nenhum registo. (A consulta
>   demorou 0.0013 segundos.).

Porém existem os valores nos registros e os mesmos estão relacionados ao registro da tbl1.

Comment: AND tbl2_criterio . Não seria AND tbl2.criterio ?

Comment: Não, é isso mesmo, o campo tem o nome de tbl2_criterio, tbl2 é a tabela e tbl2_criterio é o campo da tabela, assim fica fácil de se encontrar no código.

Comment: Ok mas então não seria tbl2.tbl2_criterio?

Comment: SIm, seria isso mesmo se houvesse alias

Comment: Acho que consegui entender.

Comment: Antes de você executar a query, como fica seu SQL? Já com o `where` adicionado?

Comment: Adicionei o $sql impresso. grato!

Comment: Faltou as nomenclaturas das tabelas na frente... tbl1. e tbl2. tenta do jeito que te mostrei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desta forma deve te servir...

Note que o campo `tbl2_criterio` é um só, e no seu SQL você está jogando ele várias vezes no `where`, logo você pede que o SQL resulte apenas os registros que o o campo `tbl2_criterio` seja igual a `valor1`, `valor2` e `valor3` ao mesmo tempo...
Para o seu caso você teria que utilizar a clausula `OR` ao invés de `AND` ou como no meu exemplo, para uma forma mais limpa, utilize o `IN()`

```
<?php
  if(isset( $_GET['var_filtro'])
  {
      $var_filtro = $_GET['var_filtro'];
      $var_filtro = explode(",",$var_filtro);
      // Imprime: 
      // $var_filtro[0] = "valor1";
      // $var_filtro[1] = "valor2";
      // $var_filtro[2] = "valor2";


      $where_filtro = " AND T2.tbl2_criterio in (";

      for($i=0;$i<=count($_GET['var_filtro']);$i++) 
      {
          if($i == 0)
            $where_filtro .= "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$var_filtro[$i]) . "'";
          else
            $where_filtro .= ",'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$var_filtro[$i]) . "'";
      }

      $where_filtro .=  ")";
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM       tbl1 T1
          INNER JOIN tbl2 T2 ON T2.tbl2_id_pai = T1.tbl1_id
          WHERE T1.tbl1_status = 'A' " . $where_filtro . ";";

  $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) 
  {
      echo $row['tbl1_row1']."<br>\n";
  }
?>
```

Obs.: Desculpe os erros de PHP, não é meu forte!

Comment: Oi, li tudo sobre o seu raciocínio e sobre o uso de IN(), desconhecia, e SQL não é meu forte mas venho estudando, se adequou bem e deu tudo certo, obrigado pela força.

Answer (score 1):

Tente dessa forma:

```
$where = "";
if(isset($_GET['var_filtro']){
    $var_filtro = $_GET['var_filtro'];
    $var_filtro = explode(",",$var_filtro);
    if(count($var_filtro)>0){
        $where .= "LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.tbl2_id_pai=tbl1.tbl1_id";
        for($i=0;$i<=count($var_filtro);$i++) {
            $where .= " AND tbl2.tbl2_criterio='".$var_filtro[$i]."' ";
        }
    }
}


$consulta = mysqli_query($conn, "
    SELECT * FROM tbl1
    {$where}
    WHERE tbl1.tbl1_status = 'A'
");
```

Comment: Oi, a sua solução resolveu em partes, tive de usar alguns ifs que ficou grande o código, obrigado pela ajuda desde a confecção da pergunta e na resposta, foi de grande valia.

Comment: Por nada, se puder, aceite minha resposta como correta e vote. Obrigado! ;)